# How to call Struts1 Action from Ajax or JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, struts

I need to call an action on load of a JSP. To keep track of number of users who visited that page.

I have an action `VisitorCounterAction`, where it updates the database.
On load of the JSP I'm calling an ajax function `callCounter()`;

```
{

        alert("callCounter");
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        // i need some correction here
        xmlhttp.open("GET",VisitorCounterAction,false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        alert("callCounter returned from Action");
        }
```

I am getting an exception as:

```
/web/guest/content?p_p_id=31&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=pop_up&p_p_mode=view&_31_struts_action=%2Fimage_gallery%2Fview_slide_show&_31_folderId=10605 generates exception: null
```

Please help me with this. Or any other way to call the Action. 
I can't reload the page as it'll call onload function again.

Thanks,
Dj

Comment: why the value of  "p_p_state" is "pop_up"?

Comment: Have you step debugged through your your action class code?  Where are you getting the null error?  I'm doing some AJAX calls using Struts 1.3 and I'm not doing anything special in my action classes so I'd guess your problem may have to do with the parameters you are sending in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct url when calling the action. In your struts.xml file you would have created an action entry with a name. Let's say that name is VisitorCounterAction. Note that this is not the name of the Action class but the name you use in struts.xml.

Also you would have configured struts to recognize a particular extension. By default it is .do.

To request the action you will then use:  VisitorCounterAction.do.

So try:

```
  xmlhttp.open("GET","VisitorCounterAction.do",false);
```

Note also the double quotes around the URL as this is a String in the xmlHttp object's open() method.

Comment: Hi,
now the exception is this(Logger info in console):
20:44:32,153 INFO  [STDOUT] 2010-02-18 20:44:32,153 [http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8080-2] WARN  com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl - Current URL /web/guest/VisitorCounterAction.do generates exception: null

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to the XMLHttpRequest object's `open` method should be a string that is the URL of the request. In your case it should be the Struts' Action Mapping that maps to your `VisitorCounterAction`. Something like:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/viewCounterAction.do", false);
```

Comment: Hi John,
My problem would be with my portal. I am using Liferay portal. it still gives the same exception. But i can see the alert msg at last.
The exception is seen in console. I dono wat to do, it is not going to Action.

Comment: Can you please tell me which Jar should be included to make my application to have AJAX, I am using Struts 1.3 version.
I have got struts2-dojo-plugin.jar, does that work for Struts 1.3 Version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Liferay 4.2, then this link might help you (http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Ajax+Toolkit). Liferay 4.2 have own set of javascript API for doing AJAX functionality(Implemented in jquery).